# How can I hide my laptop from my TV? (Samsung Smart TV)

Tags: networking, laptop, connection, ubuntu-studio, tv

On our computer, which is used by whole family, we have AllShare app installed for watching films from computer on TV. Smehow, my laptop appeared in the same place as our computer on the TV with name of my device and minidlna at the end. There is only few empty folders, if you open it. I just installed Ubuntu Studio, before Ubuntu we didn't experienced such thing. Maybe that's because my computer is connected to the same WI-FI as TV? How can I remove my laptop from there? And is it because it's kind of feature of Ubuntu (Ubuntu Studio)? Is it turned on after every Ubuntu installation?
Edit: And also, can someone do something with my computer using TV? (kind of scared of somebody using my laptop)

Comment: It's probably "Media Sharing" that is enabled by default. In normal Ubuntu the option is in in `Settings -> Sharing` but I am not familiar with Ubuntu Studio but perhaps you can find sharing settings and disable.

Comment: You may want to read the articles on this site. https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00082462/

Comment: I tried to find such setting as "Media Sharing" but it seems like there is no such thing. I'm on KDE Plasma, maybe it will be useful. The nearest thing I found is to turn on "Hidden Network" in WI-FI setting, but I'm not sure that it's the right way.